# Following strict rules as to where, randomly adding in rows to a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows

The following is a chunk of a much larger Matrix:

```
     0    1.0000    1.0000   77.0000  100.0000         0    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   72.0000  100.0000    0.2500    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   69.0000  100.0000    0.5000    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000   48.0000  100.0000    0.7500    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000    1.0000    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   71.0000  100.0000    1.2500    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   62.0000  100.0000    1.5000    0.2500
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   41.0000  100.0000    1.7500    0.2500
2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   62.0000  100.0000    2.0000    0.2500
2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   67.0000  100.0000    2.2500    0.2500
2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   71.0000  100.0000    2.5000    0.2500
2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   43.0000  100.0000    2.7500    0.2500
3.0000    1.0000    1.0000   71.0000  100.0000    3.0000    0.2500
3.0000    1.0000    1.0000   62.0000  100.0000    3.2500    0.2500
3.0000    1.0000    1.0000   67.0000  100.0000    3.5000    0.2500
3.0000    1.0000    1.0000   47.0000  100.0000    3.7500    0.2500
4.0000    1.0000    1.0000   69.0000  100.0000    4.0000    0.2500
4.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000    4.2500    0.2500
4.0000    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000    4.5000    0.2500
4.0000    1.0000    1.0000   41.0000  100.0000    4.7500    0.2500
5.0000    1.0000    1.0000   74.0000  100.0000    5.0000    0.2500
5.0000    1.0000    1.0000   71.0000  100.0000    5.2500    0.2500
5.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000    5.5000    0.2500
5.0000    1.0000    1.0000   47.0000  100.0000    5.7500    0.2500
```

etc.. the Matrix continues from this point in the same fashion:

- column 1 ascends in 1s every 4 rows: 0-0-0-0-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2...n-n-n-n
- column 2 is always 1
- column 3 is always 1
- column 4 is always 1
- column 5 is grouped in sets of 4 numbers (e.g.  [77 72 69 48] is the first set)
- column 6 ascends by 0.25 each row
- column 7 is always 0.25

In its construction the matrix is grouped in 4 row chunks, each signposted by the ascending number in the first column (0-0-0-0-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2 etc). For example, the first chunk is:

```
 0    1.0000    1.0000   77.0000  100.0000         0    0.2500
 0    1.0000    1.0000   72.0000  100.0000    0.2500    0.2500
 0    1.0000    1.0000   69.0000  100.0000    0.5000    0.2500
 0    1.0000    1.0000   48.0000  100.0000    0.7500    0.2500
```

The length of the full matrix will be around the 1500 mark, let's say: 1512

- Somewhere between every 80 to 200 rows I'd like to insert another row. Each of these inserted rows should:

• contain the number 69 in the 4th column

• contain the number 2 in the 3rd column

• contain a value in the 1st column that is +6 from that in the preceding row (i.e. if column 1 in the previous row had the value '3' then I'd want column 1 in the current row to have the value 9)

• contain a value in the 6th column that maintains the pattern of consecutively rising by 0.25 throughout the whole matrix, ie. 0, 0.25. 0.5, 0.75 (and the values in the following rows should be adjusted to continue the pattern as such)

• contain a number 0.25 in the 7th column

- Each insertion point should, as mentioned, be between every 80 to 200 rows on the original matrix. However in each instance *the point* ***where*** between 80 and 200 should be randomised (i.e. the first insertion of a row might be after, say, 84 rows on the original matrix, for the next insertion this time it might be after, say, 196 after the first one).

• The insertion point should not intersect a 4 note group:

i.e. this is a bad insertion point:

```
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   72.0000  100.0000   19.0000    0.2500
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   67.0000  100.0000   19.2500    0.2500
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   76.0000  100.0000   19.5000    0.2500
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   48.0000  100.0000   19.7500    0.2500
20.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000   20.0000    0.2500
20.0000    1.0000    1.0000   69.0000  100.0000   20.2500    0.2500
26.0000    1.0000    1.0000   69.0000  100.0000   20.5000    0.2500
```

But this is fine:

```
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   72.0000  100.0000   19.0000    0.2500
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   67.0000  100.0000   19.2500    0.2500
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   76.0000  100.0000   19.5000    0.2500
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   48.0000  100.0000   19.7500    0.2500
20.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000   20.0000    0.2500
20.0000    1.0000    1.0000   69.0000  100.0000   20.2500    0.2500
20.0000    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000   20.5000    0.2500
20.0000    1.0000    1.0000   45.0000  100.0000   20.7500    0.2500
26.0000    1.0000    1.0000   69.0000  100.0000   21.0000    0.2500
```

- For each inserted row: all values in column 1 that follow the insertion must have 11 added to them.

For example:

```
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   72.0000  100.0000   19.0000    0.2500
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   67.0000  100.0000   19.2500    0.2500
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   76.0000  100.0000   19.5000    0.2500
19.0000    1.0000    1.0000   48.0000  100.0000   19.7500    0.2500
20.0000    1.0000    1.0000   65.0000  100.0000   20.0000    0.2500
20.0000    1.0000    1.0000   69.0000  100.0000   20.2500    0.2500
20.0000    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000   20.5000    0.2500
20.0000    1.0000    1.0000   45.0000  100.0000   20.7500    0.2500
26.0000    1.0000    1.0000   69.0000  100.0000   21.0000    0.2500
32.0000    1.0000    1.0000   64.0000  100.0000   21.2500    0.2500
32.0000    1.0000    1.0000   67.0000  100.0000   21.5000    0.2500
32.0000    1.0000    1.0000   60.0000  100.0000   21.7500    0.2500
32.0000    1.0000    1.0000   36.0000  100.0000   22.0000    0.2500
33.0000    1.0000    1.0000   72.0000  100.0000   22.2500    0.2500
33.0000    1.0000    1.0000   67.0000  100.0000   22.5000    0.2500
33.0000    1.0000    1.0000   64.0000  100.0000   22.7500    0.2500
33.0000    1.0000    1.0000   43.0000  100.0000   23.0000    0.2500
```

- Finally.. for every chunk of matrix between an inserted row and the next inserted row (also including the chunk between the matrix beginning and the first inserted row, and the chunk between the last inserted row and the matrix end) I'd like to add to the original values a random number between 1 and 12. (as an example (with '2' '9' and '5' in the example being 'random numbers between 1 and 12') 'inserted_row - value+2 - value+2 - value+2 - value+2.... next_inserted_row - value+9 - value+9 - value+9... next_inserted_row - value+5..' etc)

Is anyone able to help with that?

Comment: ok - sure thing. It's technically not a duplicate as I've changed almost the entire wording to make it clearer, however it is essentially dealing with the same problem. Instead of editing the original I'll just delete the original and this question here can be its replacement (I'll delete the old one within 24 hours)

Comment: What have you tried? It's not really clear what part of this you are having trouble with.

Comment: It's probably best to presume total incompetence I'm afraid, still very much at the starting stages of trying to get my stuff together...

Comment: A duplicate is a question asking about the same problem, independently of the user/wording

Comment: ok - understood, sure thing I'll take down the other one then. Would anyone be up for having a go at answering it?